# How to hide back button in navigation bar using Xamarin.Forms - AppShell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, back-button, app-shell

Currently I'm using AppShell in my xamarin app. I need to hide back button arrow in NavBar and replace it with menu icon.
`NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"` Isn't working for me.

Comment: Can you try this in c#  ?  NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);

Comment: Do you want to hide the navbar ? or just the back button?

Comment: @Anand In c# it doesn't work too.

Comment: @AnasAlweish just back button and replace it with menu icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the custom renderer to reset the `NavigationIcon`. I use a star icon for reference.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(ShellCustomRenderer))]
namespace ShellDemo.Droid
{
public class ShellCustomRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public ShellCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new ToolbarAppearance();
    }         

}

public class ToolbarAppearance : IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void ResetAppearance(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker)
    {
        //toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.star_small);// Resource.Drawable.star_small;
    }

    public void SetAppearance(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        //toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.star_small);
    }
}

}
```

[image]